# Combine columns csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have data like this in a csv file. How do I combine all the columns together to make one number. I have tried pandas but issues with pandas lead me here cause I dont know how to do it any other way.
[image: Sample Data]

This is the output I would like

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)

results = []
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    column_data = df[i].astype(str).str.cat(sep='')
    results.append(column_data)

df.loc[len(df)] = results

df.to_csv("results.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

1. The results list is created to store the concatenated values of each column of the dataframe.
2. The for loop iterates over the number of columns in the dataframe and concatenates the values of each column using the `str.cat` method and converting the data type to `string` using `astype(str)`. converting the data into a string is necessary. This is because the `str.cat` method in works with `string` values only.
3. The concatenated value of each column is then added to the results list.
4. The `loc` property of the dataframe is then used to add a new row to the dataframe at the end with the values stored in `results list`.
5. Finally, the dataframe is saved to a `CSV` file named `results.csv` using `to_csv` method. The `index argument` is set to `False` to not save the row indexes and the `header argument` is set to `False` to not save the header.

---

Here's the result before saving to a `csv` file, with both `header` and `index` visible

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 | 22 | 13 | 41 |
| 1 | 52 | 36 | 67 | 87 |
| 2 | 91 | 150 | 41 | 12 |
| 3 | 123 | 14 | 76 | 16 |
| 4 | 155291123 | 223615014 | 13674176 | 41871216 |